# Ubuntu had my trash recovered after reinstalling

Tags: trash

So I removed Ubuntu from my computer and installed Windows 11.
I didn't empty my trash before I removed ubuntu.

After that, I reinstalled Ubuntu, but, the trash had items in it?!
I open the trash and saw my files that I trashed on my past installation of Ubuntu.

Can somebody explain to me how this works, please?

Comment: It doesn't happen unless you reinstalled Ubuntu in the same partition without formatting said partition and reused the same username and password.

Comment: Do you have a separate /home partition that was not impacted by the sequence of removals/installations of Ubuntu/Windows?